# My hlsl shader cannot unroll a loop?

Tags: c++, shaders, hlsl

I have this shader:

```
   texture tex;
   sampler2D s = sampler_state {
      texture = <tex>;
   };

   int tWidth = 1;
   int tHeight = 1;
   int blurLength = 3;

   float4 ps_main(VS_OUTPUT Input) : COLOR0
   {
      float weight = 1.0 / (blurLength * blurLength);
      float2 pxSz = float2(1.0 / tWidth,1.0 / tHeight);
      float4 color = Input.Color * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy);
      float4 outC = 0;
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;
        int numSubtr = (blurLength - 1) / 2;
        x -= numSubtr;
        y -= numSubtr;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = x; i < x + blurLength; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = y; j < y + blurLength; ++j)
            {
                outC += Input.Color * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy + float2(i * pxSz.x,j * pxSz.y)) * weight;
            }
        }
      return outC;
   }
```

When I load it I get:
[image]

What could be wrong? (using hlsl ps 2.0 I think)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `blurLength` as a `static int` for this to work.  When unrolling a loop, the iteration count has to be a compile-time constant; without the `static` on there, the compiler has to assume you might change the value of the parameter at runtime.

Comment: Well that is the thing, I do want to change these at runtime. And another thing, I tried to manually do it and when blurLength is > 3 (say 5 or 9) it does not run my shader. What can I do if I want dynamic bluring?

Comment: Not changing at runtime in this instance means not changing during shader execution.  Making the variable a constant input allows the host application code to change the value still.

Comment: @Milo PS 2.0 does not support dynamic branching, so any loops must be unrolled and must have a compile-time constant iteration count. To get blurs of different sizes, you would have to have a different shader for each blur size. As for why you can't get blurLength > 3, probably you have too many texture samples in that case. PS 2.0 only supports a limited number of texture samples. If you're doing a box or Gaussian blur, though, it is separable, so you can do it in two passes: a 1D blur on each row followed by a 1D blur on each column. That will be faster than doing it all in one pass anyway.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch Actually, in this case the blur size must be a *compile-time* constant, so the host application cannot change the value even between draw calls.

Comment: The host application can change constants between draw calls - it just requires recompiling the shader. :). You're right though that it can't be a constant input, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running out of instructions of one or the other flavor, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), SM2.0 is quite restricted. The diagnostics of the shader compiler is rather horrible at times.

> Shaders have restrictions for maximum instruction counts. Total Instruction slots: 96 (64 arithmetic and 32 texture).